# Where can I get up-to-date airline, flight, route and price data?

Tags: api

Where do sites like Expedia, Orbitz, Kayak, Bing Travel, etc. get their airline schedule data? E.g. if I was going to build some sort of site to find air travel, what data sources exist that I can use?

I've found [OpenFlights.org](http://www.openflights.org/data.html) so far but this won't get me pricing information and it doesn't have actual flight information (e.g. information for a particual flight number - just the routes) so I can't tell where the layovers, etc. are.

Comment: Is that part of the Stack Exchange? If so, can someone move my question there?

Comment: I don't think it is, it just seems to use the software (or, at least, something very like it).

Comment: How is this off-topic? APIs don't "generally relate to programming or software development in some way?"

Comment: @JoshM. Did you find any solution as I am working on same kind of things.

Comment: How dare you, Jeff Atwood, close my question! Who do you think you are, the KING of SO?!?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online shopping/booking engines either get and display the data from internal GDS or they use a direct connect (API) with the distributer or supplier

Comment: Thanks. I've moved on from this since 2011. :)